# how can i pass a value of script into html page.. eg i have calculated the size of screen and now i want to use the value in html form

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

how can i pass a value of script into html page.. eg i have calculated the size of screen and now i want to use the value in html form

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Mess</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        function alertSize(){
        var width = $(window).width();
        var height = $(window).height();
        alert(width)
        alert(height)
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="alertSize()">
    <form style="position: absolute;height : ??;width: ??">

        <div style="position: absolute;height: 50%;width:40%;top: 30%;left: 50%;background: #222930">
            <div style="position: absolute;height: 70%;width:50%;top: 10%;left: 10%;background: #4EB1BA">
                <h4 style="color: #E9E9E9">Enter User Name <input type="text" id="user"></h4>
                <h4>Enter Password <input type="text" id="pass"></h4>
                <input type="submit" id="sub" value="submit" >                
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">    
                <input type="button" value="Forget Pass" id="Fpass">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite understanding the usefulness of this, but to achieve what you're asking, you'll need to select the HTML elements using jQuery, and apply the width and heights to their CSS. For example:

```
$('form').css({ width: width +'px', height: height + 'px' });
```

Comment: i am trying to make the website resolution according to the user screen size... and everything inside will be dependent on that resolution(%) making it look like same on every resolution. if there is a better way to do this then advise me.. thank u

Comment: I would just express your width and heights via CSS in percentages.

Comment: no but it would scramble all elements when the window is re-sized.